# Export results from a R function as a CSV file

Tags: r, export-to-csv, breakpoints

Please help a newbie to R. How can I generate a CSV file that contains the results from a R function?

```
    install.packages('strucchange')
    library(strucchange)
    setwd('C\\...')
    #Import dataset
    HPD_NDVI_Mean <- read.csv('NDVI_Mean_100_yearly.csv')
    for (i in 2: length(HPD_NDVI_Mean)){
      NDVI_Mean = HPD_NDVI_Mean[i]
      NDVI_Mean_ts <- ts(NDVI_Mean, frequency = 1, start = 1988, end = 2017)
      Mean_bp = breakpoints(NDVI_Mean_ts~1)
      year = breakdates(Mean_bp)
      write.csv(year, file = 'Mean_bd.csv')
     }
```

The final results look like:

[image: a screenshot of the results]

I just want to use the detected year number after "Corresponding to breakdates", how can I make it?

p.s. 
This is how my dataset looks like, have no idea how to copy and paste my dataset here.
[NDVI_Mean_100_yearly.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsz1F.jpg)

Comment: Can you edit the question with the output of `dput(head(HPD_NDVI_Mean, 20))`?

Comment: AS @RuiBarradas pointed out we need the input to provide an answer but `print(x$'Corresponding to breakdates')` may do the job for you.

Comment: @Masoud Actually, I believe that the appropriate function is `breakdates`. I have just run the example in `help("breakpoints")` and `breakdates(bp.nile)` gives the right answer. So it would be `breakdates(x)`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas I haven't gone that far. I believe what you have found, as I know you as a credible user, is the robust solution. Cheers.

Comment: When you have the data frame you want, you can use `write.csv` or `readr::write_csv` to put it into a CSV file.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Thank for the instructions, breakdates() can help me to focus on the exact dates.Then how can I write all the results into one file? I notice only the last one was recorded. Sorry if I ask too much.

Comment: The results you show don't look rectangular, making a CSV file a poor choice. If you just want what's in your console to go to a file, you'd do better writing txt file with `cat` or `sink`.

Comment: Voting to close. Questioner has failed to offer any sort of description of either 'NDVI_Mean_100_yearly.csv' or the `HPD_NDVI_Mean` that results from it. Ideally we should see `dput(head(HPD_NDVI_Mean, 30))`

Comment: @42 I have added a screenshot of dataset to the question. Thank you. The dataset is large; have no idea how to paste it here.